# execute makefile from the command line not from sh.exe

Tags: python, windows, makefile, sh, gnu-make

I'm trying to install a python package with C/C++ bindings (PyQt4, popplerqt4). When I try to build the package (SIP package needed for the binding) I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error:unexpected end of file
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ckDf.png)

In this installation [guide](http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2007/02/23/how-to-build-pyqt4-for-windows/) they suggest the

```
/bin/sh
```

being the problem as the makefile is though to be run from the windows command line and not from the sh.exe.

in GNU **make** description I found this:

```
Choosing the Shell

The program used as the shell is taken from the variable SHELL.
If this     variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is 
used as the shell. The argument(s) passed to the shell are taken from the
variable .SHELLFLAGS. The default value of .SHELLFLAGS is -c normally, or   
-ec in POSIX-conforming mode.
```

so I would like to know how to deactivate this automatic use of the sh.exe app and how to change the shell in order to run the makefile from the command line.

thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation you have referred to, write:

```
SHELL := cmd
```

in your makefile (near the top, conventionally) to tell `make` to invoke `cmd`
as the shell program. `cmd` is the Windows shell.